# Build Failed during nutch-1.5 compiling with ant-1.5.2

Tags: java, ant, solr, nutch

I get this error while executing "ant" command from cmd on my Windows for compiling nutch to be used with java.

Screenshot link is: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6toyfdma7bqwmou/Screenshot%20%28193%29.png?dl=0

I followed this tutorial
http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2012/06/building-a-java-application-with-apache-nutch-and-solr/

Answer (score 0):

You must have missed the IVY library. Download and add in you path and try.

You can Download the same from here [IVY](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/download.cgi)